# missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' django restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I was using routers for creating urls now i want to make urls for my api, but problem is, i am getting error

> createuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

iam getting same error for all my methods inside UserAuthAPIView class, i have already read solutions on stackoverflow but they are not working i my case.

I have many methods in UserAuthAPIView class and i want to create urls for all of those.

for eg

```
127.0.0.1:8000/api
127.0.0.1:8000/api/createuser
127.0.0.1:8000/api/login
127.0.0.1:8000/api/<pk>/viewuser
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from UserAPI.api import views
from  UserAPI.api.views import UserAuthAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', UserAuthAPIView.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='user-list'),
    url(r'createuser/$', views.UserAuthAPIView.createuser, name='user-create'),
    #url(r'userlogin/$', views.UserAuthAPIView.userlogin, name='user-login'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class UserAuthAPIView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListViewSerializer

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False, permission_classes=[AllowAny], serializer_class=UserSerializer)
    def createuser(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        return Response({ "status" : "user created successfully"}, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Routers preform a couple of operations on the viewset and in particular add a mapping from the http verbs to the associated functions.

You need to do something similar for your action:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', UserAuthAPIView.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='user-list'),
    url(r'createuser/$', views.UserAuthAPIView.as_view({'post': 'createuser'}), name='user-create'),
]
```

Comment: i am getting error      AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Comment: My bad, indeed, it should be be `views.UserAuthAPIView.as_view`

Comment: i am not getting any error, but  my form fields are not showing. when i tried to put a print statement inside createuser ,i found that createuser is not running when url is 127.0.0.1:8000/api/createuser

Comment: this is a post, not a get.

Comment: url(r'createuser/$', views.UserAuthAPIView.as_view({'post': 'createuser'}), name='user-create'),

Comment: this is what i am using and still not getting form fields

Answer (score 3):

You are call the Viewset in urls in wrong way. You need do it like this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'auth', UserAuthAPIView)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Or

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'createuser/$', UserAuthAPIView.as_view({'post':'createuser'}),
]
```

Comment: router is creating urls like 127.0.0.1:8000/api/createuser which is what i want but it will also create url 127.0.0.1:8000/api/createuser/<anything>/

Comment: what should be url if i want to access any method inside UserAuthAPIView class, because as_view() is giving error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Comment: Well, it should not. You can use the **updated** answer given by Linovia or last part of my answer :)

Comment: and the url by defaultrouter will not create `createuser/<anything>/`, it will create `createuser <anything>/` (space not slash)

Comment: i have tried router and problem is url "127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/ <anything>"  is not throwing error "page not found" instead i am getting data as a response

Comment: it should be `/api/auth/createuser/` or `/api/auth/createuser <anything>/`